# Error while setting up air crack

Tags: aircrack-ng

I encountered these errors while setting up aircrack

```
chrisdabeer@localhost:~/aircrack-ng-1.1$ make install

make -C src install

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/chrisdabeer/aircrack-ng-1.1/src'

make -C osdep

make[2]: Entering directory `/home/chrisdabeer/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
Building for Linux

make[3]: Entering directory `/home/chrisdabeer/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
gcc -g -W -Wall -Werror -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -fPIC -I..    -c -o linux.o linux.c
linux.c: In function 'is_ndiswrapper':
linux.c:165:17: error: variable 'unused' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function 'linux_set_rate':
linux.c:334:22: error: variable 'unused' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function 'linux_set_channel':
linux.c:807:22: error: variable 'unused' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function 'linux_set_freq':
linux.c:896:22: error: variable 'unused' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function 'set_monitor':
linux.c:1022:22: error: variable 'unused' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function 'do_linux_open':
linux.c:1366:12: error: variable 'unused_str' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c:1352:15: error: variable 'unused' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
linux.c: In function 'get_battery_state':
linux.c:1982:35: error: variable 'current' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [linux.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/chrisdabeer/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/chrisdabeer/aircrack-ng-1.1/src/osdep'
make[1]: *** [osd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/chrisdabeer/aircrack-ng-1.1/src'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Comment: I am horrible in formatting, I was in a bit of a rush.

Comment: Chris, the question seems to be not about Ubuntu. Please post your question on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user300458 Why is this not about Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want the version available in package manager `sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng` you can take a look at this link and see if will help you compile

http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack

Download dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev sqlite
```

Download tarball, extract, compile, and install:

```
wget http://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1.tar.gz
cd aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1
make
sudo make install
```

I think the version available by apt-get (assuming on 14.04 is 1:1.1-6, but if you compile it you will get aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1)

Comment: Can you include what it is that you are referencing in the link, just in case the link moves, or goes 404?

Comment: I can't really copy from my phone. It the official site. Will be up for while